# How to implement Agile Scrum for a testing team that does BAU and project work simultaneously

Tags: scrum, agile-project-management, agile-processes

Recently, I have taken over the role as a test manager for a company. I am looking at avenues to implement agile. The team does BAU tasks and project work in parallel.

Basically, the work is shared between the team members. We have internal releases which is handled by our in house developers and external releases handled by our [COTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) supplier. I am planning to implement the following

1. Bring internal projects and BAU tasks under Agile
2. All external release and projects to remain [waterfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_model) as we depend on other agencies and external vendors.

Does this approach make sense or should I split the team into projects and BAU? Please share your experiences and thoughts.

Comment: What is *"BAU"*? [Business as usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_as_usual_(business)) (whatever that means in this context)?

Comment: You are likely to get more responses to this question in the project management stack exchange: https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would say the big problem here is, why is there a testing team?  Scrum doesn't have testing teams - development and testing is done in the same sprint, by the same team.

If there is a BAU dev team and project dev team, then think about splitting your "testing team" and inject people into each of those teams.